# Analytic solution to a Volterra integral equation with kernel divided by continous differentiable function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have been struggling with the following Volterra integral equation for days:
$$f(x)=A_{1}-\frac{A_{2}}{h(x)}+\lambda \int_{a}^{x}\frac{h^{\prime
}(s)}{h(x)}f(s)ds$$
, where a, A1 and A2 are positive constants, $\lambda$ is a negative constant, and $h(x)$ is a continuously differentiable function. It is a Volterra integral equation of second kind, and I have tried Adomian Decomposition Method or converting the problem to an ODE of initial value, but I am not able to solve it even if I consider the simplest case: h(x)=x.
Does this type of integral equation have analytic solution? May Laplace transformation help to solve it?
If I have to resort to numerical methods, are there available libraries for Mathematica, Matlab or other software I could use? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do we know if the image of $h$ contains $0$? If no, I think I can prove that there exists a continuous solution $f$...

Comment: Could you specify the domain of $f$ and $h$?

Comment: that would be great, indeed h does not contain 0. h:R+-{0}->R+ and f:R+->[0,1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can brute force this using functional analysis techniques (which I just pray you know). I assume that $h$ does not vanish on $[a, b]$ where $b>a$ and is continuous on that domain. Some steps you will have to calculate for yourself, I do not want the answer to be too long...

We equip the space $C([a, b])$ with the usual norm $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty} :=  \sup_{x \in [a, b]} \lvert f(x) \rvert$. Consider the continuous linear operator $T: C([a, b]) \rightarrow C([a, b])$,
$$
(Tf)(x) := \int^x_a k(s, x) f(s)~\mathrm{d}s
$$
where $k \in C([a, b]^2)$ is defined as $k(s,x) := \lambda\frac{h'(s)}{h(x)}$. Let $K := \sup_{(s, x) \in [a, b]^2} \lvert k(s, x) \rvert$.

Then let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be very large. We consider $T^n$, the $n$-time composition of $T$ with itself.
Then, for any $f \in C([a, b])$ and any $x \in [a, b]$ we can prove that
$$
\left \lvert (T^nf)(x) \right \rvert \leq \lVert f \rVert_\infty K^n \int^x_a \int^{x_1}_a ... \int^{x_{n-1}}_a~\mathrm{d}x_n~\mathrm{d}x_{n-1}...~\mathrm{d}x_1 = \lVert f \rVert_\infty\frac{K^n (x-a)^n}{n!}\leq \lVert f \rVert_\infty\frac{K^n(b-a)^n}{n!}.
$$
So for $n$ very large, we have that $\lVert T^n \rVert < 1$, where $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ denotes the operator norm.
Therefore the Neumann-Series $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty T^n$ converges in the operator norm. Thus $T- \mathrm{Id}$ has an inverse. In other words: For every $v \in C([a, b])$ the equation
$$
v = Tf - f
$$
has a unique solution $f \in C([a, b])$. Choose $v(x) := \frac{A_2}{h(x)}-A_1$ and you get a solution for your integral equation that is continuous on $[a, b]$.

So yes, there exists an analytic solution on compact intervals $[a, b]$, no doubt. Just iterating this argument for larger and larger intervals should give us a continuous solution on $[a, \infty)$... Maybe one can allow $x \in [\beta, b]$ where $\beta < a < b$ - which I don't expect to do any harm, but I would have to compute that separately. Then we would get a solution in $[\beta, b]$

Comment: thanks a lot. I don't follow all the steps. May I ask you what is the name of the method that you are following? I would like to understand each of the steps. Would it be too hard to get the solution for example for the case of h(x)=x?

Comment: Yes, it would be too hard for the concrete case $h(x) = x$... .  Well, the method is just called using the Neumann series. You have to learn about the terms "continuous, linear operator", "Neumann-series" and "operator norm". One can prove that the Neumann-series converges to $T - \mathrm{Id}$ if there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lVert T^n\rVert $< 1. Technically, the solution is given by $f(x) = \left(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty T_n\right) v$

Comment: But just tell me, where exactly you can't follow

Comment: It has to be $(T-\mathrm{Id})^{-1}$ in my first comment, sry

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful. I will go through Neumann-series and operator norms.

Comment: Nice, very good

Comment: This is an amazing answer, of superb quality and clarity. +1.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much :D